# Двойной AI индекс

Tags: mysql, multi-index, autoincrement

Не знаю как сделать двойной счетчик в таблице MySQL (и как его назвать). В столбце `Родитель` должен указываться ID из другой таблицы, это не столь важно

А в столбце `Счетчик` должен автоматически выставляться номер этой строки с учетом `Родителя`. Т. е. при добавлении двух строк с `Родителем` = 1 `Счетчик` должен отсчитать 1 и 2, но при последующем добавлении строки с `Родителем` = 2 `Счетчик` должен поставить в ней 1. Если потом добавить строку с `Родителем` = 1 `Счетчик` уже должен указать 3

| ID | Родитель | Счетчик |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 1 | 4 |

В итоге получается группа папок, в каждой из которых есть свои файлы, нумерующиеся с единицы

SQL позволяет сделать такое?

При добавлении меток увидел **multi-index**, вероятно, это то, что мне нужно, но я все равно не понял как это сделать

---

**UPDATE**

> Как раз узнал, что такое триггеры. Получился следующий код:
>
> ```sql
> BEGIN 
>  UPDATE parents 
>  SET parents.counter = parents.counter + 1 
>  WHERE parents.id = NEW.parent; 
>  SET NEW.number = (SELECT counter 
>                    FROM parents 
>                    WHERE parents.id = NEW.parent); 
> END
> ```

Comment: Это возможно для таблицы на MyISAM Engine - при условии что НЕ будет автоинкрементного поля `ID`. На InnoDB, или при наличии автоинкремента `ID`, придётся использовать триггер и опорную таблицу.

Comment: @Akina, тогда как это сделать с опорной таблицей на InnoDB?

Comment: В опорной таблице держите пары Родитель - Текущее значение счётчика для него. В триггере извлекаете значение и пишете в рабочую таблицу, а опорную инкрементите.

Comment: @Akina все получилось, спасибо. Как раз узнал, что такое триггеры. Получился следующий код:BEGIN
UPDATE parents SET parents.counter = parents.counter + 1 WHERE parents.id = NEW.parent;
SET NEW.number = (SELECT counter FROM parents WHERE parents.id = NEW.parent);
END

Comment: Не забудьте - во избежание проблем одновременного доступа таблицу перед вставкой записи надо блокировать.

Comment: А не лучше сделать veiw в которой оконная функция будет считать счетчик по группам, чем на каждый insert делать дополнительный update?